# How do I find the server name I'm runing?

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a web page with visual studio 2010. I want to used pass word recovery control. I need to find out what server Name is,  so I can use SMTP setting to send emails to the user who forgets his pass word. I don't know how to get it. Does anybody know. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: When you send e-mails locally, is easiest to use the `localhost` as the "server name".

Answer (score 1):

`My.Computer.Name` should do the trick in VB.  @Vache said that `My.Computer` does not exist in C#.

Or

`System.Environment.MachineName`, as pointed out by a commentor.

It looks like `System.Environment.MachineName` may be preferred, as that is a static method.  `My.Computer.Name` seems to be added at the project level; when I just tried it in the Immediate Window within a solution that has numerous projects, the call was ambiguous.  I had to fully qualify it by a project's namespace before I could get the value.  E.g., `MyNamespace.Project1.My.Computer.Name`.  However, you shouldn't have to qualify it if you call it from within a project instead of a global area like I did.

Comment: Note that `My.Computer` does not exist in C#.